# Sql agent job step to Rename a file in SQL Server 2000 fails with error " file being used by another process"

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-agent

We have a SQL agent job configured on Sql Server 2000, which has an initial step of renaming a backupfile coming from a another server (SQl Server 2000) Say coming from \A\B\X.dat to X_back.dat. till month of Feb process was running fine. However it came to our notice that step started failing with below error

*Executed as user: AUTOMATEDLOGIC\mssql. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.*

The step runs at say 8 AM and the file is delivered to above location by 7 AM. But still we get the above error.

Any suggestions what/where to look for?

Thanks!

Comment: Either the transfer is not complete or something indeed still has a lock on the file.